# Android Support SearchView: Soft keyboard Disappears as soon as it opens

Tags: android

I am using the v7 support `SearchView` as a `MenuItem`, and I am encountering a strange issue. As soon as the `SearchView` expands, the soft keyboard appears briefly and then disappears. This does not happen on all devices. My expected flow:

- User taps the `SearchView`
- SearchView expands and the keyboard is shown
- If the user dismisses the keyboard while the `SearchView` is expanded, the keyboard should reappear if the user clicks on the expanded `SearchView`.

Any help to resolve this issue will be appreciated.

My code is as follows:

**Menu XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

**The Activity's `onCreateOptionsMenu`**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_songs, menu);
    mSearchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
    mSearchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                openKeyboard(v.findFocus());
            } 
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

And finally,

**The `openKeyboard` method**

```
private void openKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
            (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, 0);

}
```

Comment: Thing is once you click he search view it has the focus. Which means `hasFocus` is true for the first time only. If you want `true` for `hasFocus`, you need to lost focus and re-focus.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I do understand, but the problem is that the keyboard just flashes once and disappears even when the `SearchView` is expanded for the first time.